# how to change http method in data driven testing in jmeter using java

Tags: jmeter, data-driven-tests

Does anyone know how to use java to change the HTTPrequest methods in Jmeter. I see a version of it but they use python. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can define whatever [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you want in the "Method" input of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler like:

[image: JMeter Use Variable in HTTP Request sampler]

Given you properly define this `${METHOD}` variable value you should be able to parameterise the HTTP Method by using external data sources, i.e. via [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

[image: JMeter Parameterise HTTP Method]

Comment: thanks man. btw, is there anyway can we use the Pre Processors like JSR223 Pre Processor?

Comment: Sure you can, in JSR223 PreProcessor it would be something like: `sampler.setMethod('GET')`, `sampler.setMethod('POST')`, `sampler.setMethod('PUT')`, etc. where `sampler` is a shorthand to parent Sampler instance, in case of HTTP Request it will be [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#setMethod-java.lang.String-), see JavaDoc for all available methods and fields and [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for information regarding using scripting in JMeter